# EF code first generated DB can be updated from code, but cannot retrieve data

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

I am using EF code first to generate my DB, it's worked. When I tried to read data from a table via:

```
var l = db.MyTable.ToList();


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I got this error. I usually because of wrong connection string. But my connection string is right. I use it to update my database and any change is right.

Comment: Are you sure you're following the convention rules? you should post your connection string

Comment: It was my fault. I tried to rename SQL server instance but there are something wrong and it still keep that instance name. Then, I got that stupid error. I uninstalled and reinstalled SQL server and it's worked. Thanks